# Overlapping divs/content

Tags: html, css

I am new to the CSS and HTML world and am struggling with my content overlapping whenever I resize my browser. If someone could take a look at my code and help me understand how to fix this issue that would help a lot! Thank you!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="java.js" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/javascript">
<link href="stylessheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Neon Angels</title>
</head>

<body class="fix">
<div id="wrapper">


<div class="section black" id="section1">
<h2 id="welcome">The Neon Angels Welcome You!
<img src="wingslogo.svg" alt="" id="top">
<img src="wingslogo.svg" alt="" id="top2">
</h2>
<p>
<img src="wings.jpg" alt="wings" width="750" id="wings">
</p>
<ul class="nav">

    <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="mouse">

<div class="mouse-icon">
<span class="mouse-wheel"></span>
</div>
</div>


</div>



<div class="section about" id="section2">
<h2 id="abouthead">About the Neon Angels</h2>
<p id="about">
    The Neon Angels specialize in painting with light photography. We absolutely love that our job consist of playing in the dark with glow sticks for hours. Our motto at Neon Angels is: "Even when it gets dark do not forget that you can glow". We are a unique company that loves abstract art, but we also do nature photography and portraits. Below you will find a video showing the process of how we work.  

</p>
 <iframe width="620" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xzjy6kTZxW0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#section1" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="mouse">

<div class="mouse-icon"  >
<span class="mouse-wheel" id="blackmouse"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="section paint" id="section3">
<h2 id="painthead">Painting with Light</h2>
<p id="painting">
    Painting with light is an art that takes time and rhythm. Normally we handle our sessions jamming out to music because it requires a type of rhythmic nature that only arises like  when music is involved. Please feel free to look through any of our pictures and if you too would like a painting session please visit our contact page. 
 </p>
 <div id="paintpic">
 <a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/angelin.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Inverted Angel"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/angelin.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
 <a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/abstract.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Abstract"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/abstract.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
 <a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/anna.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Anna"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/anna.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
 <a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/blue_light.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Blue Light"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/blue_light.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/butterfly.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Butterfly"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/butterfly.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/clash.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Clash"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/clash.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/craze.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Craze"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/craze.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/flower.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Flower"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/flower.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/greenswirl.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="greenswirl"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/greenswirl.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/halfcircle.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="halfcircle"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/halfcircle.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/mindblown.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="mindblown"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/mindblown.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/mystic.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="mystic"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/mystic.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/radiation.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="radiation"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/radiation.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/rainbow.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="rainbow"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/rainbow.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/stuckcircle.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="stuck circle"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/stuckcircle.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/swirl.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="swirl"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/swirl.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/whitelight.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="whitelight"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/whitelight.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/wings.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="wings"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/wings.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/yellow-blue.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="yellow-blue"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/yellow-blue.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/zeus.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Zeus"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/zeus.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
 </div>
 <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

 <div class="mouse">

 <div class="mouse-icon">
 <span class="mouse-wheel"></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>


<div class="section nature" id="section4">
<h2 id="naturehead">Nature</h2>
<p id="nature">
```

The reason why Neon Angels takes on nature photography is to always find the most unique perspectives. There are many places on Earth that the human eye neglects to see and that is where photography comes in.

```
</div>

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a>   </li>
    <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="mouse">

   <div class="mouse-icon"  >
   <span class="mouse-wheel" id="blackmouse"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="section portraits" id="section5">
<h2 id="portraithead">Portraits</h2>
<p id="port">
Neon Angels Photography would love to capture you in the light. </br>
Please check out our portraits for what we could do for you!
</p>
<div id="portpic">

<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0679.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Kate"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0679.jpg" width="200" height="300"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0789.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Em"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0789.jpg" width="200" height="300"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0793.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Emily"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0793.jpg" width="200" height="300"></a>
<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_3202.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Smile"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_3202.jpg" width="200" height="300"></a>
```

```
<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0986.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Davy"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_0986.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>



<a href="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_4945.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Davy "><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/Portraits/JPEG/IMG_4945.jpg" width="200" height="300"></a>
</div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section6" style="text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a>  </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="mouse">
  <div class="mouse-icon">
  <span class="mouse-wheel"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="section contact" id="section6">
<h2 id="contacthead">Contact Neon Angels</h2>
<p id="paracontact">
The Neon Angels take pride in delivering the most unique photographs around and we would love to have you as a client. Please contact Neon Angels for any quetions about paint with light photography or a consult. Thank you!
</p>
<div id="last">
 <a href="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/anna.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" title="Anna"><img class="gallery" src="gallery/src/paintwithlight/JPEG/anna.jpg" width="900" height="700"></a>
 </div>
 <p> Phone Number: 859-772-2156
 </br>
 Email: neonangels@gmail.com
 </p>

 <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1" style="text-decoration:none">Welcome</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section2" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" style="text-decoration:none">Painting with Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4" style="text-decoration:none">Nature</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section5" style="text-decoration:none">Portraits</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="mouse">

   <div class="mouse-icon"  >
   <span class="mouse-wheel" id="blackmouse"></span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<footer>  <div id="parawork"><i>Copyright &copy; May 2nd, 2016</i> |    <i>Neon Angels Photography</i></div> <img src="wingslogo-white2.svg" alt="" id="bottom"> 
<img src="wingslogo-white2.svg" alt="" id="bottom2"> 
</br>
<i>Email: neonangelsphotography@gmail.com</i>
</br>
</br>
<i> Phone Number: 859-772-2156</i>


</footer>
</div>
<script src="gallery/src/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";



*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body{

font-family:aguafina-script;
font-size: 34px;
font-style: italic;
letter-spacing:-1px;
}
#wrapper{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.section{


text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #f0f0f0;
text-align: center;
}


#top{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;  
float: right;

}
#top2{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;

}


#port{
margin-left: 300px;
margin-right: 300px;    
padding-top: 25px;
}

#paracontact{
margin-left: 300px;
margin-right: 300px;    
padding-top: 25px;
}

.section p#about{
 color:#000000;
}

.section h2#abouthead{
background:#00FFE3; 
padding: 50px;

}


.section h2#naturehead{
background:#00FFE3; 
padding: 50px;
color: black;

}


.section #welcome{
background: #00FFE3;
color:#000000;
border-bottom: thick solid #00FFE3;
border-bottom-width: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;


}
.black{
height: 1200px;
background: black;
}



.contact{
background: #00FFE3;
color:#000000;
border-bottom: thick solid #00FFE3;
border-bottom-width: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
letter-spacing: .25px;
line-height: 40px;

}
.nature{
height: 1600px;
background: #00FFE3;
color:#000000;
border-bottom: thick solid #00FFE3;
border-bottom-width: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
letter-spacing:.25px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.about{

color:#000;
background:#00FFE3;
height: 1400px;
letter-spacing: .25px;
line-height: 40px;
}

#about{
margin-left: 300px;
margin-right: 300px;    
padding-top: 25px;
}

#painthead{
padding: 50px;  
}

#contacthead{
margin: 50px;   
}

#nature{
margin-left: 300px;
margin-right: 300px;
padding-top: 25px;  
}

.paint{
height: 1700px; 
background: black;
color: white;
line-height: 40px;

}


#paintpic{
padding-left: 250px;
padding-right:250px;
padding-bottom:50px;

 }

#portpic{
padding-left: 250px;
padding-right:250px;
padding-bottom:50px;
padding-top: 50px;
}


 #natpic{
padding-left: 250px;
padding-right:250px;
padding-bottom:50px;
padding-top:50px;   
}
.portraits{
background: #000000;
color: white;
height: 1400px;
letter-spacing: .25px;
line-height: 40px;

}
#painting{
margin-right: 300px;
margin-left: 300px;
padding-bottom: 75px;
letter-spacing: .25px;
}


iframe{
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 60px;
border:thick solid #FF0086;
border-width: 30px;
}


.nav{

list-style: none;
position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;

}


.black ul li{

white-space: nowrap;
display:inline;
color:#aaa;
float:left;

}
.black ul li a{
padding:0px 10px; 
color:#f0f0f0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.black ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #80F9FF;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: aguafina-script;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.about ul li{



 display: inline;
 color:#aaa;
 padding:2px;


}
.about ul li a{
 color:#000000;

}
.about ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;

font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: aguafina-script;
color:#FF8A91;
}

#portraithead{
padding: 50px;  
}

.nature ul li{
float:left;
padding:2px;
margin:5px;
color:#aaa;
}
.nature ul li a{
display:block;
color:#222;
}
.nature ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}


.portraits ul li{

padding: 5px;
margin:5px;
display:inline;
color:#aaa;
float:left;



}
.paint ul li a{

color:#f0f0f0;

}
.paint ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #80F9FF;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: aguafina-script;
}

.paint ul li{

padding: 5px;
margin:5px;
display:inline;
color:#aaa;
float:left;



}
.portraits ul li a{

 color:#f0f0f0;

}
.portraits ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #80F9FF;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
 font-family: aguafina-script;
}

.contact ul li{
padding: 5px;
margin:5px;
display: inline;
color:#aaa;
float:left;
margin-top: 80px;
}
.contact ul li a{
 color:#000000;
}
.contact ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;

font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: aguafina-script;
color:#FF8A91;
}

 .mouse{

 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom:20%;
 margin-left:50%;


 width: 100px;
}
.mouse-icon{
width: 25px;
height: 45px;
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
.mouse-wheel{
height: 6px;
margin: 2px auto 0;
display: block;
width: 3px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-animation: 1.6s ease infinite wheel-up-down;
-moz-animation: 1.6s ease infinite wheel-up-down;
 animation: 1.6s ease infinite wheel-up-down;
}

#blackmouse{
background-color:#000000;   
}




@-webkit-keyframes wheel-up-down {
0% 
{
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
   }
30% {
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes wheel-up-down {
0% {
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
   }
 30% {
    opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}@keyframes wheel-up-down {
  0% {
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
 }
 30% {
    opacity: 1;
    }
100% {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}
}




footer{ 

background-color:black;

text-align:center;
color: white;
padding: 30px;
height: 200px;
 font-size:20px;

}
#bottom{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;  
 float: right;


}
#bottom2{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;


}
#parawork{
margin-top: 50px;   
}

#last{
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the part about your responsive video yesterday. Maybe you didn't see the code, I'll look after I see my kids for a while at the rest of what you have there

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexible-container iframe,
.flexible-container object,
.flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://b922bde52f23a8481830-83cb7d8d544f653b52d1a1621f05ea9d.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/video/landingpage.mp4" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Also add all of this Device Specific CSS Media Queries Collection to the end of your existing css  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c/raw/f5e6961faf05e923848c61a5e1e7488ec4fef83c/mediaqueries.css